# Php redirect and seo

Tags: php, redirect, seo

I have a client that uses Google Base with their eCommerce store.  They want to redirect all of their specific product links (i.e. white-large-shirt.htm, red-medium-shirt.htm) to the configurable url (i.e. shirt.htm).

This is so the customer when clicking on the white-large-shirt link in Google Base can be redirected to the page where they can select from other colors and sizes as well.  Not just the one option product page.

I can do this easily in one of the php controller files but I am wondering what the ramifications are for SEO or 'Black-Hat' redirecting.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is the code snippet I used on the product controller class.

```
//Show configurable products only
        if($product->type_id == "simple"){
            $parentId = $product->loadParentProductIds()->getData('parent_product_ids');
            if(isset($parentId[0]))
            {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentId[0]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

An SEO compliant redirect (i.e. 301 http code) will mean to Google that those page has to be merge.

So as long as you merge links too there is no problem.

But if you let those references to white-large, red-medium everywhere it will definitely look like spamdexing / Doorway pages.

Comment: Forgive me ignorance but how these bots index your site is a mystery to me.  I did not alter the URLs with a java-script redirect.  What I altered was the controller class.  If a request comes in for a simple product(red-large-shirt) then I have the controller spit out the product and subsequent URL for the configurable product(shirt).  Then the user can select red and large from the options.  Is this what you would consider spamdexing?  If so what strategies would you suggest?  I don't want to setup thousands of 301 redirects.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Oh I did get what you did. Every webpages are still here (i.e. white-large-shirt.htm, red-medium-shirt.htm) but they all display the same content. 

It's not good. It will do some duplicat content. One content should have one url / page. See what's google say about it: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359

You should set up the 301's. You don't need to leave them live forever, just the time to let Google crawler to understand the new structure.

you can find a way to set up the 301's using regular expressions. You don't need to have a line per url.

Comment: redirection will have to set up like this:
every old urls ( white-large-shirt.htm, red-medium-shirt.htm)
redirect to the new one shirt.htm

Answer (score 0):

You really need to setup a 301 redirect. This tells search engines that the old page has moved permanently. Then take Google for example will update their search engine to point all their links to the new URL.

For example if I had old.html and I renamed it to new.html I setup a 301 redirect so if anyone does go to old.html it sends them to new.html and all tells the browser that old really still exist it is just now called new.html

You mentioned changing it in a php file which makes me think you are just changing the structure I would ask you if someone went to old.html on your site would they still get to new.html?

One of the easiest ways to do this on a Linux server is to use a .htaccess file.

Example .htaccess file: 
Redirect 301 old.html new.html

You can also change complete structures using mod rewrite doing some research can help you create some fancy rules to redirect entire structures based off of variables.
If you need an overall view of how the redirect process http://www.bigoakinc.com/seo-articles/301-direct-Google.php explains it pretty well.

Comment: Hi Sam.  I added some additional comments above.  I understand your rewrite rule approach but as of yet I haven't found anything in the uri that would distinguish between the 2 types of products.

Comment: Can you give a couple examples?

Comment: Sure.  This is on the magento platform.  I edited my original question above.